# Does elastic search option to do diffrenential backup and restore

Tags: elasticsearch

Does elastic search have the option to do diffrential backup and restore. The only option I see in the document given is to take the whole snapshot of the index.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/modules-snapshots.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no way to take an incremental one, no

snapshots themselves are incremental. that means that if you take a snapshot at `$day0`, then every day after that, each of the subsequent snapshots will be whatever has changed from `$today` and `$today-1`